# Animation reverting to previous state after first frame

Tags: animation

As the title says. I was following a basic animation tutorial, set up the keyframes, then decided I wanted the parts higher. I moved them, but the animation still reverts when I play it.

I've tried this:

- Selecting all items and deleting all keyframes with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>
- Deleting keyframes via timeline (as you can see in the pictures, there are no keyframes visible)

First picture is before
Second is after

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you bake the animation? If so, you should try deleting the bake and setting the keyframes again.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to BSE. There is no problem being new to Blender and start to learn it. There are a lot of people who are willing to help you, if they are able to. And here is the problem: they can only help you if they have necessary informations to know what you have done and what you want to do. Unfortunately you didn't provide satisfying information to help you. We even don't know how you did your animation: particles? geometry nodes? rigid bodies? something else? so i would recommend providing your blend file (open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions)